# load balancer topology

Tags: load-balancing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

I am setting up a Load balancer with two backend webservers and one backend mysql server.

Is it a good idea to have dedicated mysql server ? or will it impact sql queries?

all the servers are running in one cloud zone and the latency between servers is less than 1ms

Thanks 
Sandeep

Comment: Extra power won't hurt you, generally speaking. This question, however, can't be answered in its current format. We need more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If you go with a reliable provider then for starters you can go with a single provider and diversify later. Suggestion, benchmark your setup, the cost might not justify having a dedicated mysql server from the start.

Also explore weighted round robin load balancing algorithm, might be a good idea to send lesser than 50% traffic to the server which has the mysql+web app.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to build it, profile it, try a different build and profile that.  These days, with virtual server environments and no hardware costs, it's significantly easier to try different infrastructure layouts before you go live.

So, try both, and see which is better under your anticipated load.

As the comments suggest, start simple, baseline performance under known load, and then add complexity as required to meet demand.

Comment: that works fine so far... I have this setup configured for a test site.  I am also considering to have webservers on different cloud zone to avoid the SPOF but that will surely decrease mysql queries because the latency time will increase

Comment: how are the other companies running their setups I've seen hosting companies runing a separate mysql server other than web server

Comment: Most "other companies" started with a simple setup without any redunandancy, load balancing etc. They gradually improved their setup so they could meet their requirements.

Comment: +1 on Oliver's comment, start simple, get it working and then add the other elements!